Validation Result is same as Training Result in YOLOV8
I'm a beginner please spare me, I'm running a YOLOV8 model in Google Colaboratory Environment. I've noticed that after training my model and validating it with the pretrained yolov8 model.  Then I've noticed that validation result is same as my training result. Is that even possible? or my code has a problem?
I have a limited data a very small data.
Training Images : 153 images (training images has been augmented importing imaugh library)
Validation & Testing Images: 22
Please refer to the images for reference
Training result\
Validation result
Well I've tried the validation code using from the  YOLO docs result is still the same.

At the end of the training process, the trained model is validated on a val set. The same result you will observe if you directly call model.val() on your trained model. Please note that in both of your cases, the image count is the same: 11, this means that more likely the model was validated on the same data set in both cases.

You must have different datasets during training and validation. If you train your model on same data and validate in the same data. You will get the same results. Use this command for training results = model.train(data="coco8.yaml", epochs=100, imgsz=640)
and validation_results = model.val(data="coco8.yaml", imgsz=640, batch=16, conf=0.25, iou=0.6, device="0") for validation.
